# How to get Guest telephone number from Order in Sales_Order table

Tags: magento2

I want to fetch Guest telephone number from their order, as I checked from the Database I found the telephone number is saved in `sales_order_address` not in `sales_order`. How do I get this data? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve it from order `object`.

Load your order (using object manager for simplicity, generally you should use dependency injection instead)

```
$id = "your_order_id";
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($id);
```

Now you can get the address phone data from the shipping address like this:

```
 $order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone();
```